# Assign variables in batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm new in Windows batch programming and I have found problems in the variable assignment. This is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Video=1
set FILEMEDIA=outputMedia.txt
for /f %%a in (%FILEMEDIA%) do (
    set /a Video=%Video%+1
    @echo Video
    set file=%%a
    @echo file
)
```

If FILEMEDIA has two lines I would like to obtain Video=2 and the line in file variable. However, at the end I obtain Video=1 and an error when I tried to print file (echo is off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of duplicate with [How do I increment a DOS variable in a FOR /F loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913231/how-do-i-increment-a-dos-variable-in-a-for-f-loop)

Variables that should be delay expanded are referenced with `!VARIABLE!` instead of `%VARIABLE%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Video=1
set FILEMEDIA=outputMedia.txt
for /f %%a in (%FILEMEDIA%) do (
    set /a Video+=1
    @echo !Video!
    set file=%%a
    @echo file
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Maybe `@echo !file!` instead of `@echo file`